# Mysql Subquery select

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to find a solution:

I need query that selects all Tasks which not `started` and similar tasknames of this Tasks should not be more 5 rows repeated in this tables with flag `started`

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks as t 
WHERE started = 0 
AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks 
WHERE started = 1 AND taskname = taskname) < 5)
```

But query not working. Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: not working = not the result he expects

Answer (score 3):

try the following

```
AND taskname = t.taskname
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks as t 
WHERE started = 0 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks 
WHERE started = 1 
AND taskname = t.taskname) < 5
```

You just needed to compare the count result rather than include the comparison in the sub query. Also, you needed to qualify the taskname to the outer table by using `t.` prefix

Comment: There is no `ast_limit` in his query. I don't know where you copied that from.